# Recover Wrong encoded string values in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I have a database in which I store the `alt` and `title` values of the images. Unfortunately the program which inserts these values hasn't been connecting to the MySQL database with a UTF-8 link and the data it has inserted to the database is not in Unicode. I have fixed that but I was wondering if there is some way to retrieve the original values from the database and convert them to Unicod

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

1. Dump your table data with `mysqldump` or any other favorite tool
2. Fix encoding in dump file using one of the utilities (there are plenty out there)
3. Load data back